# Should a regular expression used to break up lines account for unix/dos issue?

Tags: c#, regex, portability

I didn't feel like using XML for the input file of my T4 so I made this snippet that splits up a document into chunks separated by a blank line.

Am I appropriately making the carriage return optional here?

```
string s = @"Default
Default

CurrencyConversion
Details of currency conversions.

BudgetReportCache
Indicates wheather the budget report is taken from query results or cache.";

string oneLine = @"[\r]\n";
string twoLines = @"[\r]\n[\r]\n";

var chunks = Regex.Split(s, twoLines, RegexOptions.Multiline);

var items = chunks.Select(c=>Regex.Split(c, oneLine, RegexOptions.Multiline)).ToDictionary(c=>c[0], c=>c[1]);
```

Note: I would never have thought of this, but since I started using Git, I have seen it "say" things that reminded me of the unix2dos issues, which in turn made me think of Mono and finally if I needed to deal with portability (assuming the goal is perfection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expressions doesn't do what you think that they do. Putting `\r` inside a set doesn't accomplish anything; the expression `[\r]\n` means the same thing as just `\r\n`.

You can make the work using the `?` operator:

```
string oneLine = @"\r?\n";
string twoLines = @"\r?\n\r?\n";
```

However, I would suggest that you use the regular `String.Split` method instead of regular expressions:

```
string[] oneLine = { @"\r\n", @"\n" };
string[] twoLines = { @"\r\n\r\n", @"\n\n" };

var chunks = s.Split(twoLines, StringSplitOptions.None);

var items =
  chunks.Select(c => c.Split(oneLine, StringSplitOptions.None))
  .ToDictionary(c => c[0], c => c[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should allow for different line separators, but that's not how you do it.  The square brackets don't make their contents optional, and you aren't taking the old Mac-style `\r` into account.  I'd use these regexes:

```
string oneLine = @"\r\n|[\r\n]";
string twoLines = @"(?:\r\n|[\r\n]){2}";
```

That's "carriage-return + linefeed OR carriage-return OR linefeed".

Also, you don't need the Multiline option.  It only changes the meaning of the `^` and `$` anchors, which you aren't using (and don't need to use).

Comment: I'll see your OS-9 and earlier Mac, and raise you an IBM EBCDIC machine using `\u0085` for newlines ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go full hog on portability (and yes, I'm only adding this answer in response to Alan's mentioning of old Mac-style \r) then you want to cover:

*nix style: `\n`

DOS/Windows style: `\r\n`

Old Mac style: `\r`

EBCDIC style: `\u0085` (probably slightly more current-day use than old mac, I'd guess).

Line-separator formatting character: `\u2028`

Paragraph-separator formatting character: `\u2029`

Let's just not dwell on the precise semantics of `\u000B` and `\u000C` and turn this into something sensible (eventually). If we *were* to try to deal with all of those. How would we do it?

With 6 different line-breaks, one of which is a combination of two of the others, but which should not be treated as two line-breaks, dealing with this in the reg-ex itself could be nasty.

Much better would be to filter them all out in a TextReader wrapper:

```
public class LineBreakNormaliser : TextReader
{
  private readonly TextReader _source;
  private bool isNewLine(int charAsInt)
  {
    switch(charAsInt)
    {
      case '\n': case '\r':
      case '\u0085': case '\u2028': case '\u2029':
      case '\u000B': case '\u000C':
        return true;
      default:
        return false;
    }
  }
  public LineBreakNormaliser(TextReader source)
  {
    _source = source;
  }
  public override void Close()
  {
    _source.Close();
    base.Close();
  }
  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if(disposing)
      _source.Dispose();
    base.Dispose(disposing);
  }
  public override int Peek()
  {
    int i = _source.Peek();
    if(i == -1)
      return -1;
    if(isNewLine(i))
      return '\n';
    return i;
  }
  public override int Read()
  {
    int i = _source.Read();
    if(i == -1)
      return -1;
    if(i == '\r')
    {
      if(_source.Peek() == '\n')
        _source.Read(); //eat next half of CRLF pair.
      return i;
    }
    if(isNewLine(i))
      return '\n';
    return i;
  }
  public override int Read(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
  {
    //We take advantage of the fact that we are allowed to return fewer than requested.
    //ReadBlock does the work for us for those who need the full amount:
    char[] tmpBuffer = new char[count];
    int cChars = count = _source.Read(tmpBuffer, 0, count);
    if(cChars == 0)
      return 0;
    for(int i = 0; i != cChars; ++i)
    {
      char cur = tmpBuffer[i];
      if(cur == '\r')
      {
        if(i == cChars -1)
        {
          if(_source.Peek() == '\n')
          {
            _source.Read(); //eat second half of CRLF
            --count;
          }
        }
        else if(tmpBuffer[i + 1] == '\r')
        {
          ++i;
          --count;
        }
        buffer[index++] = '\n';
      }
      else if(isNewLine(cur))
        buffer[index++] = '\n';
      else
        buffer[index++] = '\n';
    }
    return count;
  }
}
```

If you read the file via this text reader, then from this point on your regex can depend the only newline being `\n` and so can any other code.

This done, the regex can actually be simpler than ever, and you while it's totally overkill for this single case (and only written because after Alan's mention of OS9 and earlier the idea of supporting IBM EBCDIC machines amused me), it is reusable for all other cases, in which context it's actually not over-kill at all, because it becomes "just use the well-tested line-normaliser to make things simpler". (Once it is well-tested that is, I haven't tested any of the above).

Comment: If you like this, you'll love §5.8 of the Unicode Standard: http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode4.0.0/ch05.pdf#G10213 And possibly enjoy Unicode Standard Annex #14 http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/